# MOSS/SharePoint 2007 Subsite navigation tool tip shows the word 'Subsite' - users not too happy about it

Tags: sharepoint, moss, sharepoint-2007

Not fully SharePoint xpert...yet quite functional. So, I understand 'SharePointish'...
Here is the problem...the subsite navigations- MOSS2007* (the look has been customise) show the tool tip with the word 'subsite'. which it is but Customer not too happy with that. To be fair....when you hover over a menu link 'About US' - the tool tip should be a tip attached the an example with the toooltip...

Appreciate your response.
~JustE

(Ok-Stackoverflow - didn't like me because I have been just reading and not answering your Questions :))
I couldnt'post the image)

But if you hover 'ABOUT US' - the tool Tip shows 'About Us subsite'

Comment: Can some one explain me what JustE wants to ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you check what was entered as the description while Creating the Site ? 
The tooltip is whatever is entered into description.

You can edit the description by going to Site Settings -> Title, description and Icon.

Comment: Thanks Madhur. You are right....my mistake was my assumption that only pages had those properties.